# How to write Rails rspec feature test for a custom gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rspec-rails

Where may I find guides on how to write a Rails rspec test that utilizes the ajaxful_rating gem. The test I'm writing is something like the one below.
https://github.com/edgarjs/ajaxful-rating

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.feature "Users can create new review" do
  scenario "with valid attributes" do

    # Put in a 5 star rating here.

    fill_in "Review", with: "This place is pretty good."
    click_button "Create Review"

    expect(page).to have_content "Review has been created."
  end
end
```

Comment: To select a 5 start rating you need to click on the element that is the 5th start - unfortunately the demo app linked to from the ajaxful-rating page is down so I can't see what the html it generates is -- if you add the html it generates on the page to your question we can tell you how to click it

Answer (score 0):

This could be a very broad answer however if you want to learn how you can write test case in rspec, [this documentation](http://everydayrails.com/2012/03/19/testing-series-rspec-models-factory-girl.html) can be helpful to understand the concept of what is test case and how you can make.